# Why is no argument in a function prototype preferred?

Tags: c++, coding-style, void

I have a question about coding style in C++.

I prefer to use `void` explicitly in function prototypes.

However, during reading an article about [`void` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) in Wikipedia, I have seen that giving no argument in a function prototype is preferred.

- Why is no argument in the prototype preferred?

I am so curious if there is a specific reason.

Comment: It's not necessary and shorter to type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ had function prototypes before C did, and C++ has 'always' required prototypes in effect.  Therefore, there was no problem or ambiguity about empty brackets (parentheses) meaning no arguments.

By contrast, C did not acquire function prototypes until long after C++ had them, and it had a legacy base to deal with.  Until function prototypes were introduced, C functions with non-integer return types had to be declared as:

```
double sin();
char *malloc();   /* There wasn't void * -- or C++ style // comments */
struct whatnot *new_whatnot();
```

The C standardization committee could not afford to break all the existing C code; the standard would have failed.  So, the C standardizers adopted `sometype function(void)` to indicate explicitly 'no arguments'.  To this day, `sometype function()` means 'a function returning a `sometype` value taking an undefined (but not variable) number of arguments of undefined type'.

Because C++ had the empty brackets (empty parentheses) notation, there was no need for the `(void)` notation, but it was added to C++ to match the C standard and make it easier to migrate code between standard C and C++.

- Code written natively for C++ *should* use the native, empty brackets notation.
- Code written natively for C *must* use the explicit `(void)` notation because the empty parentheses means something quite different (and relatively undesirable).
- Code written to be migratable between C and C++ might use the explicit `(void)` notation to ensure that both compilers see the same specification.

Answer (score 1):

What is prefered and what is a good practice are quite different. I believe that is just a choice of the programmer.